# How do I configure two instance of Azure Mobile Services to use the same application key?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I would like to deploy a second instance of our azure mobile service (in the US) and configure azure traffic manager so that each client will be routed to the best instance based on their DNS. This requires that a client shouldn't care which instance they get but at the moment they have to use an application key to access the service and the applications keys are different for both instances. Through the portal I can regenerate a key but I can't set it. Is there a way in which I can make this work?

Thanks

F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the application and master key using command line tooling like so:

```
azure mobile key set <SERVICENAME> master <NEWVALUE>
```

You can read more about doing this here: http://chrisrisner.com/Using-the-Same-Client-Side-User-with-Multiple-Azure-Mobile-Services.

Note though that you'll need to think through how your services do data access.  It's possible for each of the mobile services you generate to point to their own database (i.e. my data is in a US DC and your data is in a EU DC) but if traffic manager routes someone to a different mobile service than they usually use, their data won't be there (unless you've set up data replication).  Alternately you can point multiple services at the same database (not difficult with the .NET backend, more difficult with the Node backend) though then you're dealing with at least one mobile service having to leave it's DC to access the data.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That perfectly answers my question. On the down side when I went to setup traffic manager it looks like it doesn't support azure mobile services!